# convert div content into image in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, html2canvas

I've already tried html2canvas with some hack so it can be used in IE8 but it still not working. the problem is toDataURL() is not working in IE8. I've commented it so I can create just the canvas but not showing anything either. It works on Chrome.
Can you please guys tell me what to do ? or there is another solution beside html2canvas in IE8 ?

btw I want to do is convert my div content into image and download it by clicking button. For example there is button named "Download image", then the button convert my div content to image and download it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you **http://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/**

```
$(function() { 
    $("#button").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#div"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
                // Clean up 
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It is working in IE9 for sure. If it doesn't work try [VML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: it seems I can't see the demo above in IE8. the page not loaded. And the code is much alike as mine. And it doesn't support in IE8.

Comment: it's true that I want to convert my image to base64, but I have to capture the image not upload it. Btw I have tried including flascanvas.js and it kinda work creating canvas in IE8. But another problem occur, IE8 not know toDataURL() function which is my final goal to download the image. I'm so desperate right now :(

Comment: I found this http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/ and it runs on server side, but it cannot capture the current page. Like when there is a expanded tree it won't capture the expanded display.